# Qt clickable canvas

Tags: qt, qwidget

I'm really new to Qt and I don't want anything complex. All I need is to be able to declare some sort of rectangle and then be able to click on it and also draw in it.

None of the tutorials I've found include anything to get the click on an object (I'd like if possible to distinguish between left and right mouse buttons and also get the coordinates of the click and any subsequent moves).

Tutorials for painting show how to directly paint on a window or dialog but I've already placed some buttons there to help with the controls.

I don't think the drawing part is the problem, it's more the clicking part. Do I need to create a new `QWidget`? Is that difficult?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways that you can do custom drawing. I'll order them roughly from high-level to low-level:

1. Use **Qt Quick / QML / QDeclarative**. QML allows you to use Javascript and provides access to the standard Qt APIs. If your needs are simple, basic straight lines, etc., this could be a really easy way to write your app. See the [QML Examples.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeexamples.html)
2. Use **QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView**. You'll need to understand models and views to use this, but this will give you all the architecture and support you need to draw just about anything. See the [Graphics View examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/examples-graphicsview.html).
3. **Subclass QWidget** and implement the drawing and mouse handling yourself. This fairly low-level approach might be really simple if your needs are quite basic. With this approach you control everything and will eventually need to translate coordinates to things being drawn on the screen. The [Tetrix example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-tetrix-example.html) might be a good starting point.

With the last approach, you'll need to implement the right virtual methods in order to get access to the mouse events:

```
virtual void mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
virtual void mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
virtual void mouseReleaseEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
```

You'll also need to implement custom painting by overriding the [paint event](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent). The [AnalogClock example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-analogclock-example.html) goes into detail on all the steps of custom painting.